# How do you set up session hash in setup for tests in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http, session, tdd

I have the following test that passes:

```
test "should create order" do
    assert_difference('Order.count') do
      post :create, { :message_text => @order.attributes }, { :var_name => 1 }
  end
```

Instead of adding `, { :var_name => 1 }` to each HTTP call, how do I add the session to the setup method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inside a controller test you can access `session` just like you can `flash`.

here's a helper I use for setting the program's id

```
def set_current_program(program=programs(:direct_debit))
  @current_program = program
  session[:program_id] = @current_program && @current_program.id
end
```

or in the setup, you could do

```
def setup
  session[:var_name] = 1
end
```

then just do your test as usual

```
test "should create order" do
  assert_difference('Order.count') do
    post :create, :message_text => @order.attributes
  end
end
```

You can even assert the value of session, if the action should have changed it

```
assert_equal 24, session[:something_changed]
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy. I should have tried it. I hope someone finds this question useful!